# How to do pointer arithmetic on UnsafeMutablePointer and get String in Swift 3

Tags: swift, pointers, pointer-arithmetic

I am looking at this line in Objective-C:

```
NSString * str = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:data + 1 length:length - 1 encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Where the variable data is of the type 'UnsafeMutableRawPointer?'.

My attempt to convert that line to Swift 3 is as follows:

```
let next = data + 1
let dataPtr = next.bindMemory(to: String.self, capacity: Int(length - 1))
let barcode = dataPtr.pointee
```

However, I am getting a EXC_BAD_ACCESS exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to bind the raw pointer to an `UInt8` pointer:

```
let bytes = (data + 1).bindMemory(to: UInt8.self, capacity: length - 1)
```

Now you can create a *buffer pointer* referring to that byte range

```
let buffer = UnsafeBufferPointer(start: bytes, count: length - 1)
```

which (as a `Sequence`) can be passed to

```
let str = String(bytes: buffer, encoding: .ascii)
```